# UiPath.AI.ComputerVision.Activities Download

Tags: uipath

I'm getting trouble when I go for additional packages "UiPath.AI.ComputerVision.Activities" using manage packages. It shows me blankly.

[image: Manage Package]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure UiPath's Beta NuGet Feed.

1. Open Manage Packages
2. Click the Settings tab
3. Add a new User defined package source for `https://www.myget.org/F/uipath`

After that,

Install UiPath.UiAutomation.Activities package v19.2.0 from the Offical feed and when installing `UiPathVision` make sure that `Include Prerelease` is checked.

References:

- [How to add the UiPath Beta activity feed](https://forum.uipath.com/t/how-to-add-the-uipath-beta-activity-feed/96314)
- [AI Computer Vision is Now available for Preview](https://forum.uipath.com/t/ai-computer-vision-is-now-available-for-preview/95730)
- [About the AI Computer Vision Activities Pack](https://activities.uipath.com/docs/about-the-ai-computer-vision-activities-pack)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As stated on their website:

> The first incarnation of the Computer Vision Activities pack is
>   released in Beta and can only be downloaded from the Beta feed. For
>   more information on how to install the beta feed, please go to our
>   Forum [here](https://activities.uipath.com/docs/about-the-ai-computer-vision-activities-pack).